# Mixing MVC 1 and MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to have a project use MVC1 in certain areas and use MVC3 in other areas?
I have some previous code written but I was thinking of using MVC 3 to add other features.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just upgrading? What things do you need from MVC1 that you can't use in MVC3? There are breaking changes, but it's very likely that you won't run into any of them, or that you can upgrade those parts of your code to run the entire app on MVC3.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to mix ASP.NET MVC 1 and ASP.NET MVC 3 in the same ASP.NET application. And that's a good thing because you should never even attempt to do this. They should be in separate applications if migration is not an option for you at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge I think we can use MVC1 code by adding following code in web.config file.

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
 </runtime>
```

Please correct if I am wrong.